# InvalidOperationException Helixtoolkit SharpDX Element3DPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpdx, invalidoperationexception

I am using SharpDX to display a model from an .obj file.

My application is structured like this

```
MainViewModel (with MainView)
   |__ SomeViewModel (with SomeView)
   |__ SomeOtherViewModel (with SomeOtherView)
      |__SomeNestedViewModel (with SomeNestedView)
```

In the MainView there is a Menu which allows to select either SomeView(Model) or SomeOtherView(Model).
The views of SomeViewModel and SomeNestedViewModel each contain a Viewport3DX and display a Model:

```
<hx:Viewport3DX  EffectsManager="{Binding EffectsManager}" 
                 Camera="{Binding Camera}" 
                     AllowLeftRightRotation="True" ModelUpDirection="{Binding UpVector}"
                     ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True"
                     IsHitTestVisible="True"
                     IsPanEnabled="True"
                     Margin="5">
                 <hx:AmbientLight3D Color="{StaticResource ModelAmbientLightColor}" />
                 <hx:Element3DPresenter Content="{Binding Model}" />
</hx:Viewport3DX>
```

In MainView there is a ContentControl bound to the CurrentViewModel (which is either SomeViewModel or SomeOtherViewModel).

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The SomeOtherView also contains a ContentControl with a Binding to ViewModel (->SomeNestedViewModel).

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel}" />
```

When I start the application, everything looks good. The model loading happens in the constructors of the viewmodels and the model is displayed correctly in both views.
The view displayed on startup is the SomeView, and on menu click I can switch to SomeOtherView (with SomeNestedView embedded). When I switch back to SomeView and than again to SomeOtherView, an InvalidOperationException occurrs (translated with Google translate):

> Specified element is already the logical child of another element.
> Disconnect it first.

With following lines at the top of the stack:

> at
> System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement.ChangeLogicalParent(DependencyObject
> newParent)    at
> System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement.AddLogicalChild(Object child)
> at
> HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX.Element3DPresenter.<>c.<.cctor>b__7_0(DependencyObject
> d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
> e)

When I remove the Element3DPresenter from one of the views or remove the nesting and display SomeNestedView directly in the MainView, everything works fine, no exception. Same if I don't reuse the viewmodels, but newly create them each time the according menu item is clicked.
I read some explainations online and understand, that I somehow have to remove an item (I guess its the Element3DPresenter) from the logical tree, but I still don't know how to do this. Since I am using MVVM and only updating the Element3DPresenter via bindings.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't put non-english text in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to replace that. Update is in the text now.

Comment: @tabina I just ran into this same issue... were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Yes. In each view that contains a Viewport3DX, I added some code in code-behind: in the Unloaded event I remove all content from the viewport. In my case the content was wrapped in a GroupModel3d, so I call group.Children.Clear() in the unloaded event.